# Sample Mule flow to get data from Amazon s3 to Salesforce

Tags: aws

I have an s3 bucket where a csv file is present which holds certain data about an object. I would like to dump that file data into salesforce using the Mule ESB.
I was able to connect salesforce and Mule, the problem is designing with the flow. I am new to MULE, could anyone help me to build a flow to get that file into salesforce. Detailed steps will be of more help.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: While not strictly off-topic, I'm not sure that we can help you with this. You might at least consider cross-posting on [SO], which has a much larger audience with a wider range of knowledge, so you might have better success there.